# How to change a global variable from within a for if...?

Tags: python

My program tries to guess if an input number or letter is in a specific string. For that I have this simplified piece of code:

```
obtained = False

for i in range(6+len(chosen_set)):
  try_let = input("Input something")
  for index, letnum in enumerate(chosen_set):
    if letnum == try_let:
      obtained = True
    else:
      obtained = False
  if obtained:
    # do something
  else:
    # do something else
```

Say I input the letter "R" and the string I'm testing is XXXRXRX. When the inner for loop goes through its 4th iteration, the variable `obtained` will be True, and the same will happen for the 6th iteration, but not for the last one, which means the final value of `obtained` will be False. How should I change my code so that `obtained` will be True as long as it finds a coincidence regardless of when it finds it? Note that I can't use break in the for loop as soon as it finds a coincidence because the string could have more than one coincidence.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just test if `string in input` and if it is set the obtained to True?

Comment: Why can't you use break? You only want to know **IF** a match was found not **WHERE** it was found. Also, take a look at the *in* operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that?

```
for i in range(6+len(chosen_set)):
  try_let = input("Input something")
  obtained = False
  for index, letnum in enumerate(chosen_set):
    if letnum == try_let:
      obtained = True
  if obtained:
    # do something
  else:
    # do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use a `break`, then change the logic of using an explicit `True/False` boolean as the primary decision factor and make use of a `count` as well.

For example:

```
count=0
if letnum == try_let:
    count+=1
if count > 0:
   obtained = True
else:
   obtained = False
```